# Find Familiar Spell & Scrying

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

When a wizard is using their familiar to spy on a creature or location, does an Amulet of Proof against Detection and Magic prevent the wizard from seeing the person wearing the amulet?

Does Non-Detection prevent seeing a deep gnome?

Comment: Did you meant "Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location" https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/amulet-of-proof-against-detection-and-location ? If not, what is the source of the item?

Comment: You have two questions in one.  The question about the deep gnome is about a racial feature of the deep gnome, but the opening question is about a familiar.  This format works best in a "one question one answer" approach.  Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how to get the most out of this format.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As KorvinStarmast said, we have a policy of asking one question per post. You should edit your second question out of this post and ask it separately (but search to make sure it hasn't already been answered first), as well as explaining what you're trying to understand in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 6):

### Neither prevents being seen

Either directly or through your familiar’s senses.

**[Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Amulet%20of%20Proof%20against%20Detection%20and%20Location)**

> While wearing this Amulet, you are hidden from Divination magic. You can't be targeted by such magic or perceived through magical Scrying sensors.

**[Nondetection](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Nondetection#content)**

> The target can’t be targeted by any divination magic or perceived through magical scrying sensors.

Yours and your familiar’s eyes are neither “divination magic” nor “magical scrying sensors.”  They are therefore unaffected by that amulet's magical features.